# Redux form initialValues not working for the state method

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I tried to load with initial values for the form in two ways.
First inside the `FormComponent` like

```
FormComponent= reduxForm({
    form: 'initializeFromState' 
})(FormComponent)

FormComponent= connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: { name: 'ABC' }
    }),
)(FormComponent)

export default FormComponent
```

This is the copy of the document in the Redux form library, but the value is not populating in the form. The form name and variable name i used for the rest of the codes are correct.

The second method is by passing the `initialValues` from the `ParentComponent` like

```
<FormComponent initialValues={{ name: 'ABC' }} />
```

which gives the form populated correctly with name `ABC`.

What is the issue in the first method?

I tried with consoling the `this.props` in both methods inside the `FormComponent`.

First method gives `initialValues: { name: 'ABC' }` which the value is not populated in the form.

Second method gives 
`initialValues: Map
size: 1
__altered: false
__hash: undefined
__ownerID: undefined` 
which is in the format something for the redux form and works correctly for the form.

I just want to use in the first method. What changes should i make to work it correctly?

Comment: try changing your unique identifier for your form from `'initializeFromState'` to `'FormComponent'` ?

Comment: Is that required to have the same name for the component and the form?

Comment: I am not too sure but i think so. But it totally depends on where you are using it.